# check the existence of program with specific process name

Tags: linux, bash

```
Read=$((ps -eaf | grep "$name" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'))
Read1=$((ps -p <$Read>))

if [ $Read1 -ne 0 ]; then
exit 1
```

This is what I get so far, I want to first get the pid of the $name, then check whether there is process corresponding to that pid. If there is not, exit 1.

I am not sure about this.

Comment: Please check the man pages of `pidof` and `pgrep`

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, please!

```
pidof <process name>
```

Comment: I do think we have to find the process first?

Comment: `man pidof`, 1st line: "_pidof -- find the process ID of a running program._"

Comment: what if the the a process called $name  does not actually exist?

Comment: By default ps , pgrep, pidof give info about an existing - running process. If process is not running will not be listed. Are you looking to find an loaded/running process or to view installed apps? Different story.

Comment: Don't forget the `-x` option to identify running scripts, as well as the program running the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would use for this purpose:

```
test="$(ps aux | grep -sie "process-name" | grep -v "grep -sie")"
if [ -z "$test" ]; then exit 1; else echo "Process found ----- $test"; fi
```

This code is case insensitive (ex.: it would match "process-name" but also "Process-NAME").